# How to return all the translations in Shopware 6 "Store API"?

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api

I want to grab all categories through `/store-api/category/` endpoint with all translations at once from my Shopware website. I am currently able to grab translations by modifying the URL, such as '/de/store-api/category/' for German translations and so on. But I want all translated instances in one go. Is that possible?

Comment: Out of interest: What are you trying to accomplish? Showing multiple languages at once at the store front?

Comment: Actually, the store front is a multi-lingual app. I wanted to get all translations of the categories in one go instead of on-demand and on language change so that the user faces less page refresh. The app has only 3 supported languages, so it seemed practical enough to have all the translation fetched and stored in memory.

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not possible via the store-api. The store-api uses the current sales channel context to determine the language to be used. It's a customer-facing API and as such meant to only serve data associated to the corresponding sales channel. For collecting data in a larger scope, you can use the [backend-facing admin-api](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/admin-api/8d53c59b2e6bc-shopware-admin-api).